# Setting up a SVN repo through HTTPD server

Tags: macos, apache, svn

I am trying to create a svn repo on my machine(OSX 10.9). I have default Apache HTTP Server configuration and I can access all files and folders through a web browser with my IP in LAN.

- I have create a SVN repo in my Apache document root folder:

  `svnadmin create foobar`
- Now when I checkout

  `svn checkout http://x.x.x.x/svn/foobar`

  I get the error `svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://x.x.x.x/svn/foobar'`
  But I am able to checkout with the following command-line

  `svn checkout file:///path/to/foobar`

  Could some one point out what went wrong here ?

Comment: @bahrep It sure did. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It's not enough just to put the repository in Apache's root folder. You have to setup Apache HTTP Server to serve Subversion repositories. It requires you to enable and configure `mod_dav_svn` module, see [SVNBook | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

  When you use `file://` URL, you access the repository locally. I.e. it does not involve Apache HTTP Server at all. That's why it works this way. See [SVNBook | Supporting Multiple Repository Access Methods](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html#svn.serverconfig.multimethod).
- If you can't setup Apache HTTP Server, you can use `svnserve`. It's configuration is simpler than of HTTPD. See [SVNBook | svnserve, a Custom Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html).

BTW, you can install [a Subversion+HTTPD server package](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) (e.g. VisualSVN Server or Subversion Edge) if you don't want to deal with manual setup. These packages don't support OSX, though.