# How to Enable HTTP Protocol for TortoiseSVN repositories in LAN, OS : Windows Server 2008

Tags: apache, http, svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed WAMP and TortoiseSVN successfully in Windows Server 2008. We have LAN enabled for multiple Developers, I am trying to enable the HTTP protocol to access the Repositories so that the multiple developers can commit from their computers. Please help me in fixing this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a SVN repo through HTTPD server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551790/setting-up-a-svn-repo-through-httpd-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TortoiseSVN is just a Subversion client,
2. Installing WAMP package and putting your repos in it's directory is not enough. You must [configure HTTPD with `mod_dav_svn` module](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) properly.

   If you don't want to deal with manual Subversion+HTTPD server configuration (not an easy task, in fact), then you can install [a Subversion+HTTPD server package](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) (e.g. VisualSVN Server or Subversion Edge).